# implementations of strncmp, strncat, strncpy

Tags: c, beginner, strings

> Write versions of the library functions `strncpy`, `strncat` and `strncmp`, which operate on the most `n` characters of their argument strings. For example, `strncpy(s, t, n)` copies at most `n` characters of `t` to `s`. Full Description in Appendix B.

Here is my implementation of `strncmp`:

```
int custom_strncmp(const char *s, const char *t, size_t n) {
    while(n--) {
        if(*s != *t) {
            return *s - *t;
        }
        else {
            ++s;
            ++t;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `while` loop will run until `n` reaches the value `0`, or until the characters that `s` and `t` point to are not equal. At each iteration I check if the `*s` and `*t` are equal; if they are, I increment `s` and `t`. If they are not equal, I return their difference.
After the loop stops, the value `0` is returned.

Here is my implementation of `strncat`:

```
char *custom_strncat(char *s, const char *t, size_t n, size_t bfsize) {
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    char *pend = s + slen; 

    if(slen + n >= bfsize)
        return NULL;

    while(n--)
        *pend++ = *t++;

    return s;
}
```

This version of `strncat` is a secure one. The first `if-statement` checks if there is enough space in the `s` buffer to store the contents of `t`. The `while` loop will run until `n` reaches the value `0`. At each iteration the value that `t` points to is copied in to `*s`. 
After the loop stops, is returned a pointer to the result.

Here is my implementation of `strncpy`:

```
char *custom_strncpy(char *s, const char *ct, size_t n) {
    char *saver = s;

    while(n--)
        *saver++ = *ct++;
    *saver = '\0';

    return s;
}
```

The `while` loop will run until `n` reaches the value `0`, at each iteration the current character that `ct` points to is copied in `*saver`. After the loop stops, the `'\0'` is copied in `*saver` and a pointer to the result is returned.

The exercise can be found at page 121 in K&R second edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've misinterpreted the [definition of strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/), which says,

> Appends the first `num` characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character.
>   If the length of the C string in source is less than `num`, only the content up to the terminating null-character is copied.

`n` is the maximum number of characters in source you you want to copy, and `bfsize` doesn't exist in the standard version of `strncat`.

```
char destination[256];
strpy(destination, "foo");
strncat(destination, "bar", 2);
// expect destination should now contain "fooba" !
```

It's good of you to write a custom version with an extra parameter to make it safe, but that's not what the question asked for.

See also [Manual Reference Pages  - Strn (3)](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=Strn) (e.g. `Strncat` instead of `strncat`); or, [the Microsoft versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbyd7s1y.aspx) of the 'safe' functions have `_l` as a suffix.

I'm not sure that returning null and doing no copy is the standard way to avoid buffer overflow.

---

In your `custom_strncmp` method, I'm not sure what correct behaviour should be if you call

```
strncmp("foo", "foo", 10);
```

Your function might return 0 or non-zero, or crash, depending on what's after the end of the string.

You could perhaps write it more elegantly as a for loop:

```
for ( ; n--; ++s, ++t) {
    if(*s != *t) {
        return *s - *t;
    }
}
```

---

In `custom_strncat` you don't handle the condition where `n > strlen(t)`.

---

Your parameters could (should) be better named, e.g. `source` and `destination`. Parameter names are important (even more important than good names for local variables) because they may be the only documentation about how the function should be called.

Answer (score 4):

Years later, but for completeness ... `custom_strncpy` above is not compatible with standard `strncpy`.

1. It writes `n+1` characters into destination (only `n` is correct).
2. It reads past `\0` of source string.
3. It does not `\0`-pad destination string if source is smaller.
4. it always `\0` terminates. (strncpy will not in case strlen(source) >= `s`).